# Why is function not called when virtually-rendered only

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to understand when the function body of the `Label` function I have here will run.

```
export default function App() {
  const label = <Label>Foo</Label>;

  return <Button>{label}</Button>;
}

const Button = (props) => {
  const shouldRenderChildren = false;

  return <button>{shouldRenderChildren && props.children}</button>;
};

const Label = () => {
  console.log("runing Label function");
  return <span>label</span>;
};
```

I created a Codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/why-is-label-method-not-called-zodvn4?file=/src/App.js

Notice how in the `Label` function there is a `console.log`. I virutally-render this component before the `return` statement in `App`. I was expecting this function would have been called. However trying that Codesandbox above, we see it is not called as there is no `"runing Label function"` seen in console.

If I change `shouldRenderChildren` to `true` in `Button` then we see that the `"runing Label function"` log to console, so we see `Label` is called. Here it was virtually-rendered and dom-rendered.

Does `React.createElement` not actually call the render method unless it gets dom-rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of "dom-rendered", the word you *might* looking for is mounted.

When it comes to functional components, the body of the function is the equivalent of the `render` method in class components; Therefore, the function does not run until the component is being rendered.

If we look at the component [life-cycle diagram](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) once again, we can see that a component is not rendered, until it is ready to start mounting.

[image]

Therefore, I believe that at the very most, this line

```
const label = <Label>Foo</Label>;
```

is just calling the [constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) for the component. This is what the docs says about the constructor:

> The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted

If you want to test it, the convert your component to a class component, and add some console.log to the constructor, then see what happens when you do: `const label = <Label>Foo</Label>;`

### EDIT

I tested it, and not even the constructor of the component is invoked when it is not mounted:

https://codesandbox.io/s/why-is-label-render-not-called-vt05we

Therefore, it might best to assume that until a component is about to be rendered, it is not even constructed!

Comment: Oh! This makes sense! Thank you! I tested by adding a `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect` in the functional component to see if those would run, as we usually expect that to run on "mount" but they didn't run. So probably you are right, it's just the constructor! Super cool. I was working on a parent component called `<AuthenticatedOnly>` and I didn't want the children to render until the query in wrapper succeeded, it looks like it will work!

Comment: @Noitidart I didn't test this answer. I just did and not even in a class component constructor was the console.log called. It only happens when rendering

Comment: Wow thank you @smac89 really appreciate that test! So I bet even the `componentDidMount` of the class component will not trigger, as you're right we should think of it as "mount" not "virtually-render".

Comment: @Noitidart yes indeed not even `componentDidMount` will be triggered because it looks like the component is not even constructed until it is first rendered

Comment: Oh wow very interesting, thank you very much for this help and tests @smac89! I've been doing react for years, and can't believe I never realized this!